# X11 on a dedicated server

Tags: x11

I discovered X11, and I was wondering if it is possible to install it on a **dedicated server**, and have a "desktop" from the server running on my personnal computer ?

Or maybe it is necessary for the server to have a screen ? Or a least kde or gnome ?

What I want is a desktop of my server (as if it had a screen), but **on my laptop**, through internet. I want to be able to launch **graphic applications** remotely, as if it was a PC.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No monitor is necessary for what you're trying to do.

Just install the X server and your preferred vnc server (I like tightvnc), add them to the default runlevel so that after each reboot they come up by default and then you are good to go.

Comment: I will need to install KDE or Gnome on the server ?

Comment: It all depends on your needs. With X installed you can start an empty X server and open apps in it. If you need somekind of window manager you obviously need to install it. Gnome, KDE, wmii, fluxbox or whatever; it doesn't really matter.

Answer (score 2):

Just try X11 Forwarding via SSH. It's very convenient and easy to configure

You need not any monitors or video cards on your server, which is just headless.

Yes, you should need Gnome or KDE if you want to a complete desktop.

If having no desktop environment, you still can run single graphic application in your laptop.
(try xclock, xlogo etc.)

I highly recommend you to use an one-stop solution in Windows, that's MobaXterm.

Answer (score 0):

This is certainly possible.  The X terminology can be confusing here: "server" (usually) means the local machine (with keyboard, mouse, video card) and X client is the remote machine actually executing the program you're "looking" at.

You don't need VNC.

Comment: Okay so it is possible, with a "X client" on my laptop to connect to a "X server" on a dedicated server (without screen, and maybe no graphic card), and show me a desktop ? And maybe i will need to install a desktop no ? like gnome or kde ? Else what will it print ?

Comment: "X client" and "X server" are reversed - the "X server" is the screen you're looking at, the "X client" is the remote program.

Take a look at this: http://users.telenet.be/mydotcom/howto/linux/xremote.htm

Comment: Please re-read what i wrote, I know what a server and a client application are.

Comment: Yes, I believe you do, and in X terminology they're *backwards*.

Comment: Oh my bad I apologize, I should have re-read what you said. Ok but if I launch a X client on the server (with X server on my laptop), what will I get on my screen ? Will I be able to launch graphic applications in windows, and have a desktop and all?

Comment: remote applications (Xclients on the "server" machine displaying on the Xserver running on your desktop) will pop up windows and look just like they do when you run them on the "server" machine's desktop.  If you want a full desktop (like you're at the server) you'll need XDMCP or VNC.